# Unable to see files in sdcard of emulator

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am using inteeij Idea IDE I try to push files using fileexplorer of ddms it doesnt giv an error but files are not pushed on sdcard. I also try to push files through adb in cmd and it says that files are pushed but i am unale to see any files in file explorer.

Comment: can you try to install any file manager app on your emulator!

Comment: I have a project which needs files to be run these files should be added in sdcard. I have pushed files both from adb and also through fileexplorer but i am unable to see files on sdcard and my app is also not getting these files

Comment: have you tried to see sdcard files on fileexplorer on your development tools?

Comment: yes i but i am unable to see those files. There is no files in sdcard option in fileexplorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you upload file from DDMS, then after uploading file go to emulator then click on `menu->Dev Tools->Media Scanner` then open file explorer

Comment: yes sir i uploaded both from ddms and from adb through cmd but the problem is this i should see files fileexplorer sdcard option. i am not getting any error but i am also not getting files pushed in sdcard

Comment: try to upload file from DDMS Perspective